# How to reload entity mapping file in dynamic-map mode of Hibernate without restarting the application?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Hibernate ORM has a feature called [Dynamic Models](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/persistent-classes-dynamicmodels.html), which enables you to define entity with XML file, instead of POJO. Say I have a table called `EVENTS` defined as following.

```
CREATE TABLE events
(
event_id bigint NOT NULL,
event_date timestamp without time zone,
title character varying(255),
CONSTRAINT events_pkey PRIMARY KEY (event_id)
)
```

And the mapping file defined as following:

```
<class entity-name="Event" table="EVENTS">
    <id name="id" column="EVENT_ID" type="long">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="date" type="timestamp" column="EVENT_DATE"/>
    <property name="title" type="string"/>
</class>
```

Now I added a column to table `EVENTS` by `alter table events add column col_1 varchar(30)`, and inserted an record by `INSERT INTO events (event_id, event_date, title, col_1) VALUES (4, current_date, 'test title3', 'col1 test');`

Also I added one line into the mapping file as following

```
<class entity-name="Event" table="EVENTS">
    <id name="id" column="EVENT_ID" type="long">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="date" type="timestamp" column="EVENT_DATE"/>
    <property name="title" type="string"/>
    <property name="col_1" type="string"/>
</class>
```

However I can't retrieve the newly added column if I don't restart the application to make Hibernate reload the mapping file. Is it possible to reload the entity schema from mapping file without restarting the application? Thanks.